# exception name 'main_page' is not defined

Tags: django, nameerror

I am new to django.  setup is ubuntu server.  Have created a project, database, edited the settings.py, views.py, urls.py files.  Created a template folder and a main_page.html file.  All this from django:visual quickpro book.  I keep getting a name error when I run the development server.  It says the name 'main_page' is not defined.

Here is the urls.py;

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^$', main_page),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'chapter2.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^chapter2/', include('chapter2.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here is the views.py;

```
# Create your views here

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

def main_page(request):
  template = get_template('main_page.html')
  variables = Context({'head_title': 'First Application',
    'page_title': "Welcome to our first application',
    'page_body': "This is our first application, pretty good, eh?'})
       output = template.render(variables)
  return HttpResponse(output)
```

I figure there is a syntax error in the book, it was catered to much for windows or I just am missing something obvious.  I have worked on it for hours, but don't see the problem.  I hope someone can help.

Thanks,
Bobby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of your urls.py, add this:

```
import app.views   # where "app" is the name of your app
```

Then change your line in urls.py to be this:

```
(r'^$', app.views.main_page),
```

Comment: Thanks.  Had to fix a few syntax errors here and there, but it's working at last.